# continue a call from asterisk by call file

Tags: asterisk

Good day. I had configure a call file and extension file to generate auto call to a certain phone number. With the following configuration Call get disconnected after 2 sec automatically when received a call on phone.

```
Call file
Channel: SIP/voipswitch/971556710011
MaxRetries: 5
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 45
Context: default
Extension: 971556710034
Priority: 1

extensions.conf
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=yes


[default]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/provider/${EXTEN:})
exten => _X.,3,Hangup();
```

Now my query how can I continue call from asterisk until manually disconnected or hangup call from phone or receiver of the call. During the call may play a sound file or keep it silent.

Thanks and regards
Mr ZAED

Answer (score 0):

This call file and dialplan have call first phone, connect to second phone at provider and bridge calls.

It have not be disconnected, unless you have issues with provider or sip nat settings.